# How the compiler knows whether to extend zeros or ones?

Tags: c++, c

```
   int main()
   {

       char c = -1;
       unsigned char u = -1;

       printf("c = %u\n",c);
       printf("c = %d\n",c);

       printf("u = %u\n",u);
       printf("u = %d\n",u);
    }
```

The result is:

```
c = 4294967295

c = -1

u = 255

u = 255
```

When I try to convert it into unsigned int

Because of sign extension I got `c = 4294967295`

But when I try to convert the unsigned char into unsigned int

I got u = 255

in the first case 1 extended by 16 bits and printed that number

in the second case 0 is extended.

But my question is how the compiler detects whether to extend zeros or ones when it is going to fit small data into a large memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned numbers (such as your `u`) will not be sign-extended, they will be zero-extended.  That's because they have no sign!  Signed numbers (i.e. variables of signed integral type) are always sign extended.  The confusion may come from your initial assignment of `-1` into an unsigned type--once it's assigned, there is no longer a possibility for sign extension.

Comment: @JanakiramReddy How does it know what? The type of the variable? You told the compiler. If you mean how to extend, the standard regulates how numbers are extended.

Answer (score 2):

The printing involves two steps.

a) The 8 bit chars (signed/unsigned) are converted to 32 bit

b) The 32 bit values is printed as signed or unsigned

So after step a) c=0b1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111.1111 while u=0b0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000.1111.1111 due to the rule described by John Zwinck.